# Helidon : Caused by: io.helidon.webclient.WebClientException: Request failed with code 302

Tags: java, webclient, helidon, helidon-webclient

I'm writing a helidon web-client, I'm getting

```
Caused by: io.helidon.webclient.WebClientException: Request failed with code 302
```

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import io.helidon.media.jsonp.JsonpSupport;
import io.helidon.webclient.WebClient;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.json.JsonArray;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
@Path("/consumer")
@RequestScoped
public class ConsumerController {
    
    private String producerUrl="http://localhost:8080/books-db/";
    
    @GET
    public JsonArray getBookData(){
        System.out.println("producerUrl :: "+producerUrl);
        try {
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUri(producerUrl)
                .addMediaSupport(JsonpSupport.create()).addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();
                return client.method("GET").request(JsonArray.class).get();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    
    }
}
```

The entire stack trace is:

```
2023.08.09 12:17:27 INFO io.helidon.common.LogConfig Thread[main,5,main]: Logging at initialization configured using classpath: /logging.properties
2023.08.09 12:17:27 INFO io.helidon.microprofile.server.ServerCdiExtension Thread[main,5,main]: Registering JAX-RS Application: HelidonMP
2023.08.09 12:17:28 INFO io.helidon.webserver.NettyWebServer Thread[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1,10,main]: Channel '@default' started: [id: 0xeba066a3, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:9090]
2023.08.09 12:17:28 INFO io.helidon.microprofile.server.ServerCdiExtension Thread[main,5,main]: Server started on http://localhost:9090 (and all other host addresses) in 1019 milliseconds (since JVM startup).
2023.08.09 12:17:28 INFO io.helidon.common.HelidonFeatures Thread[features-thread,5,main]: Helidon MP 3.2.2 features: [CDI, Config, Health, JAX-RS, Metrics, Open API, Server]
producerUrl :: http://localhost:8080/books-db/
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.helidon.webclient.WebClientException: Request failed with code 302
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.Single.get(Single.java:730)
    at com.oracle.controller.ConsumerController.getBookData(ConsumerController.java:25)
    at com.oracle.controller.ConsumerController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBookData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    at io.helidon.webserver.jersey.JerseySupport$JerseyHandler.lambda$doAccept$6(JerseySupport.java:339)
    at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:117)
    at io.helidon.common.context.ContextAwareExecutorImpl.lambda$wrap$7(ContextAwareExecutorImpl.java:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: io.helidon.webclient.WebClientException: Request failed with code 302
    at io.helidon.webclient.WebClientRequestBuilderImpl.getContentFromClientResponse(WebClientRequestBuilderImpl.java:682)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.MultiMapperPublisher$MapperSubscriber.onNext(MultiMapperPublisher.java:73)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.SingleFromPublisher$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(SingleFromPublisher.java:86)
    at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:117)
    at io.helidon.webclient.WebClientRequestBuilderImpl.runInContext(WebClientRequestBuilderImpl.java:641)
    at io.helidon.webclient.WebClientRequestBuilderImpl$1.onComplete(WebClientRequestBuilderImpl.java:674)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.DeferredScalarSubscription.complete(DeferredScalarSubscription.java:92)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.MultiFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageSubscription.accept(MultiFromCompletionStage.java:72)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.MultiFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageSubscription.accept(MultiFromCompletionStage.java:52)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.MultiFromCompletionStage$AtomicBiConsumer.accept(MultiFromCompletionStage.java:95)
    at io.helidon.common.reactive.MultiFromCompletionStage$AtomicBiConsumer.accept(MultiFromCompletionStage.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at io.helidon.webclient.NettyClientHandler.lambda$channelRead0$7(NettyClientHandler.java:190)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRunNow(CompletableFuture.java:819)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRunStage(CompletableFuture.java:803)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenRun(CompletableFuture.java:2195)
    at io.helidon.webclient.NettyClientHandler.lambda$channelRead0$9(NettyClientHandler.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:887)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2325)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at io.helidon.webclient.NettyClientHandler.channelRead0(NettyClientHandler.java:176)
    at io.helidon.webclient.NettyClientHandler.channelRead0(NettyClientHandler.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:280)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    ... 5 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) is used for redirects.

Postman probably follows redirects by default, however Helidon WebClient does not. You need to use `.followRedirects(true)` on either WebClient.Builder or request instance.

Comment: thank you for responding back, I was returning the 302 from my downstream application. I changed it 200. It's working fine now.